# Как можно считать текст с картинки или с браузера

Tags: python, текст, браузер, искусственный-интеллект, веб-сайт

Есть определённый сайт, в который каждый день надо подтверждать определенных людей.
Есть ли способ считать информацию, кто есть в откликах, и подтвердить только определённых людей (т.е. получить координаты кнопки и нажать на нее)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужна помощь, чтобы какой-то скрипт на питоне опознал, что за человек есть в откликах. Есть ли какой-то способ, как это сделать? И чтобы несильно загружал пк, потому что это удалённый пк и он не мощный.

```html
<div>
  <div class="v-dialog__container" persistent="">
    <!---->
  </div>
  <div class="my-5 pa-5 rounded-lg v-card v-sheet v-sheet--outlined theme--light" style="border-color: rgb(21, 183, 66);">
    <div class="row align-center">
      <div class="col"><span class="rounded-xl px-8 font-weight-regular white--text v-chip theme--light v-size--default primary"><span class="v-chip__content">Есть отклик</span></span>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p class="subtitle-1 mb-0 primary--text text-right">Количество откликов: 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-auto"><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--icon v-btn--round theme--light v-size--default primary--text"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-eye theme--light"></i></span></button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-content-center">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <p class="text-h6 mb-0">Сборка интернет-заказов (Казань)</p>
          <p>№0</p>
          <p>ул.адрес</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p class="subtitle-1 font-weight-light grey--text mb-0">Казань</p>
        <p class="subtitle-1 font-weight-light grey--text">180 ₽</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p class="subtitle-1 font-weight-light mb-0 grey--text">07.01.2024</p>
        <p class="subtitle-1 font-weight-light grey--text"> 08:00</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-auto"><button type="button" class="mx-2 v-btn v-btn--fab v-btn--outlined v-btn--round theme--dark v-size--default primary--text"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-chevron-up-circle-outline theme--dark"></i></span></button></div>
      <div
        class="col col-auto"><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--outlined v-btn--rounded theme--light v-size--large primary--text"><span class="v-btn__content">Отменить</span></button></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate mdi mdi-star theme--light amber--text"></i><span class="font-weight-black">4.95</span></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col"><a class="subtitle-1 font-weight-bold text-decoration-underline black--text mb-0"> Фамилия имя отчество </a><span class="text-h6"></span></div>
      <div class="col">
        <p class="subtitle-1 font-weight-light grey--text mb-0">+12345678910</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p class="subtitle-1 font-weight-light grey--text mb-0">Нет комментария</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="spacer"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-auto"><button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--outlined v-btn--rounded theme--light v-size--large primary--text"><span class="v-btn__content">Одобрить</span></button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: selenium webdriver python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/index.html)

**pip install -U selenium**

Драйвер для FireFox - [geckodriver-v0.34.0-win32.zip](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

**Наличие самого браузера FireFox обязательно.**

Пример:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# Путь к исполняемому файлу драйвера Firefox (GeckoDriver)
gecko_driver_path = r'C:\Users\Amgarak\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.34.0-win32\geckodriver.exe'

# Путь к исполняемому файлу браузера Firefox
firefox_binary_path = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'

# Инициализация опций браузера Firefox
firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path

# Инициализация сервиса для драйвера Firefox
firefox_service = FirefoxService(executable_path=gecko_driver_path)

# Инициализация веб-драйвера с указанием сервиса и опций
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=firefox_service, options=firefox_options)

# Открытие веб-страницы
driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1560508/Как-можно-считать-текст-с-картинки-или-с-браузера?noredirect=1#comment2809998_1560508")

# Ожидание появления элемента (замените "xpath" на нужный селектор)
element_xpath = "/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div/div"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element_xpath)))

# Нажатие на элемент
element.click()

# Ожидание появления нового элемента 
element_xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div"
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, element_xpath)))

# Получение текстового содержимого элемента
element_text = element.text
print("Содержимое блока:", element_text)

# Закрытие браузера
#driver.quit()
```

`Что бы получить нужный селектор(xpath): FireFox -> ПКМ(мышка) по странице -> Исследовать ->  Выбрать элемент со страницы(пиктограмма мышки слева)  -> находим нужный div ->  щелкаем по нему ЛКМ -> затем щелкаем ПКМ по нему же ->  Копировать -> Xpath`

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо, не подскажите тогда еще как можно получить текс на определенным участке странице таким же способом?

Comment: @adeltut Дополнил ответ. Не забудьте его принять, если он вам помог.